# Number Limits of Ajax FileUpload Control in a Aspx page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use multiple FileUpload Control in an .aspx page, when i am using five FileUpload controls in page , it works fine and returs successfull fileuploading on submit button.

But when i am exceeding more than five, and trying to upload by hitting submit button, pages goes offline and browser shows like this:

> The connection was reset
>        The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>     The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
>       moments.
>     If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
>       connection.
>     If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
>       that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Why happening like this?
Is there any numbering limitations to use Ajax FileUpload?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanx

Ravindra Kumar

Comment: I will probably regret asking, but I will bite... Why do you need more than five upload controls on one page?

Comment: Actualy i have to store 7 diffrent images of a product  in data base... while adding a new product to store.

Comment: And why does that necessitate separate upload controls? Can you not reuse the same control for uploading the different images?

Comment: In the past I've used PLUpload with great success, Kumar.  It is a true multiple upload add-in.  You may want to look at that if you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, the server connection is timing out.  Are you storing the uploaded data to a database, or just a local folder?

In any case, I'm pretty sure it's related to the file size being larger than the default max file size.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28VS.80%29.aspx specifically maxRequestLength.  Increase that in your web.config and it should resolve your timeouts.

Comment: Thanx a lot Neely! It was the size issue only, Now it`s working great....... Thanx again.